# attaching an object to the Zend form

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form-element

I started to create a  Zend form :

```
$form = new Form_ChangePersonalDetails(
                     array( 'person'=>$person,
                            'emailvalidator'=>$validator,
                              ));
```

where the person is an object. It works, although it shows a  warning :

```
Warning: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given
```

Is it possible to remove this warning somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement your own constructor! :) Say

```
public function __construct($person, $emailValidator, $options) {
    parent::__construct($options);
    $this->_person = $person;
    //or if you want to fill the form with the object's data
    $this->populate($person->toArray());
    $this->emailField->addValidator($emailValidator);
}
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, my version didn't work, because of using an array  for the form elements. With your version it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

By default, any unrecognized options passed to the constructor of `Zend_Form` will be treated as additional form attributes that get added to the `<form>` tag.

If possible, add a `__toString()` method to the `Person` class so it can be cast to a string, or depending on what you are trying to do with that object, you may need to override `Zend_Form::__construct()` so it recognizes that you have passed a special object, and it can deal with it before calling `Zend_Form::__construct()` to deal with any other options passed to the form constructor.

What in particular are you trying to do by passing that object to your form constructor?

Comment: if I remove the array and use these elements one after the other, also change the parent::__construct($options) to parent::__construct() the warning is disappear. So yeah, you were right, it's dealed with the construct.